# Weird padding in Crypto.Util.Padding.pad() function in python

Tags: aes, padding, ecb

I'm trying to pad some plaintext to be a multiple of 16 bytes to use it as input in AES ECB block cipher.

```
 def encrypt(plaintext):
    plaintext = bytes.fromhex(plaintext)
    padded = pad(plaintext, 16)
    cipher = AES.new(b'0'*16, AES.MODE_ECB)
    try:
        encrypted = cipher.encrypt(padded)
    except ValueError as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
    return {"ciphertext": encrypted.hex()}
```

I understand that AES is a block cipher and it accepts 16byte blocks as input. But what I need to know here is that when I'm actually providing the function with 16byte block, why is it the padding function adding another 16byte block as follows

```
plain = "123456789abcdefg"
plain = plain.encode("utf-8").hex()
encrypt(plain)
```

```
plaintext:  b'123456789abcdefg'
padded:  3132333435363738396162636465666710101010101010101010101010101010
```

Why does that happen ?

Comment: I love this question, because I've seen this in a CTF once and used the base idea as an exam question.

Answer (score 3):

In the event that the plaintext is a multiple of the blocksize, PKCS#7 padding specifies that an additional block be added. For 128-bit blocksize, this block is all `0x10` bytes, showing 16 bytes of padding.

The reason from this is to that recipient can distinguish between (for example) a 15-byte message and a 16-byte message with the same leading 15-bytes and final byte `0x01`.